# How to update the logo of an android app in playstore?

Tags: android, google-play

How to update app logo as play store app icon? I changed in the app manifest, but its not changing while i am updating the app.I use this code in Android Manifest Application tag

> android:icon="@mipmap/ic_app_logo"
> android:logo="@mipmap/ic_app_logo"

Comment: Where did u change this? application tag??

Comment: please read these: [ask] & [mcve] & [help/on-topic], to increase your chance of getting answers to your questions!

Comment: make sure you have changed image in mipmap folder

Comment: @JanardhanR yes i changed in there also

Comment: @AishwaryaTiwari Manifest inside Application tag

Comment: clean app and the n rebuild if this doesnt work post you r manifest

Comment: @JanardhanR its changing in app icon,their is no problem. But in playstore it showing my previous version icon.

Comment: @BenjithMathew, app_icon(app launcher icon) and app logo on google play both are different thing. You set app icon(launcher icon) in `AndroidManifest.xml` using `android:icon="@drawable/icon"`. To change app logo on Goolge Play store you need to upload it there specifically of size 512x512 as suggested by Janardhan in below answer.

Comment: @Geek ok thank you

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Ok then you should change your app icon in developer console which is 512*512
go to store listing in developer console and change Hi-res icon (app icon) as it will override your icon in app.